# Calling setup_postdata() causes "Call to undefined function get_userdata()" error?

Tags: get-posts

The exact error is:

> Call to undefined function `get_userdata()` in /wp-includes/query.php on line 3567

I am using `get_posts()` in my plugin, which in turn uses `setup_postdata()` wherein `get_userdata()` is executed. I have no clue what's going on. I looked at `query.php` and it looks like `get_userdata()` is a global function, it shouldn't have any problem accessing it right?

**MORE DETAIL**:

My plugin is in a class form. This is just the basic structure. There are multiple functions in the actual code actually. Please take note of the `get_posts()` function where the post query occurs. If I remove it, the error won't show up.

```
class myPlugin() {
   var $post_type = '';

   function __construct($post_vars = array()){
       if ($post_vars) $this->post_type = $post_vars['post_type']
       $this->get_posts();
   }

   function get_posts() {
       $args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' = $this->post->type, 'post_status' => 'publish');
       $myposts = get_posts( $args );
       foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
           print_r($post->ID);
       endforeach;
   }
}

return new myPlugin($_POST);
```

If I place the query in functions.php(and maybe outside the class or function scope which I have not tried), it works. That's my workaround for now, but I'd like to integrate it into my plugin.

Comment: I guess you're at a point where this kind of stuff so far isn't ready. Please show where you hooked in.

Comment: @kaiser well I guess you didn't answer my question. In fact that's the only certain thing I can gather in this page so far.

Comment: I **didn't answer** your question. I **commented and asked for more detail** (update your Q): A) Where do you have this code? B) Where do you **hook in**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding a `return new CLASSNAME( $data );` at the end of a file(?).

You need to make that call inside a function and add the fn callback to a hook like this:

```
// THIS IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE!
function wpse46288_call_the_funk()
{
    return new CLASSNAME( $data );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse46288_call_the_funk' );
```

Comment: Yup that's the last line in the file. I see, if this will work, I'll send you a beer. =) If you don't mind, could you elaborate your answer?